# How to filter out everything except the laser light using linear array sensor

Tags: filter, laser, image-sensor

I use [iC-LF1401](http://www.ichaus.de/iC-LF1401) to capture line 128 x 1 in horizontal position. Parallel to this linear sensor, I've mounted linear laser (vertical light). How can I filter out linear sensor output, clear all except laser light?

Maybe some modulation? But how to do it?

For first tests i will use this [linear laser](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-650nm-5mW-Red-Laser-Line-Module-Focus-Adjustable-Laser-Head-/400746941596?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5d4e610c9c)(5V 650nm 5mW), hope it will be ebough for ~5-6 meters

Comment: What colour (wavelength) of laser are you using? How much time is their to sample the whole device?

Comment: @gbulmer thanks for the answer, i i've edited post

Comment: How many samples per second is needed? The time available to capture a sample may effect the answer. What will capture the signal, for example what MCU are you using?

Comment: @gbulmer hmm, i don't know for sure. Deck with sensor and laser will rotate around the axis. I think it should be as much as possible)

Comment: "as much as possible" isn't a good engineering specification. What happens if it is as fast as possible, but 10x too slow to work in your application? For example, would 30mS be okay?

Comment: @gbulmer 30 frames per second will be slow, i think it will ~1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is typical is to use a narrow band wavelength filter to knock out all but the laser wavelength.  But keep in mind that the bandpass of this filter will be angle dependant.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i i've edited my post, laser is (5V 650nm 5mW), which filter i should use?

Comment: @Kracken, placeholder is talking about an interference filter.  One of these would be perfect, but they are expensive.   Browsing through the thor labs catalog, filter FB650-40 would work it's ~$100.  (I picked a wider bandpass for you because the diode laser wavelength is only nominal.)  If that's too much money then modulation of the laser light and some sort of synchronous detection might work.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Is there are filters for 650nm, but freeform? Like a paper?) like IR filter)

Comment: @Kracken - similar to George Herold, I had did a search, and found http://opticalfiltershop.com/shop/bandpass-filter/visible-bandpass-filter-650nm-fwhm-100nm/ where a bandpass is about $29 for something big enough to cover that sensor. Coloured plastic film might help enough to be worthwhile.

Comment: @Kracken,  There are colored glasses and plastics.  Most of these are long pass filters..they pass all wavelengths below some corner (Kind of like a low pass.)  You could get a red one of these and it would block everything above red.  (Better than nothing.)  I had a sample stack of plastic filters from Lee filter... these are more photography type things.. though there were some specs.

Comment: @Kracken,  there are colored glass and plastic filters.  These are mostly long pass filters.  (They pass all wavelengths longer than some corner wavelength.)  You could get a red one and it would be block all the light above red.  A good glass one at Thor labs is still $35.  I have a sample pack of plastic filters from Lee filter.  Really for photography, but some of them have transmission data.

Answer (score 1):

Make two measurements, first with laser on, then with laser off. After that, just compute difference between the two.

You have to process the entire array at once. When used with MCU that has fast ADC, high framerate (thousands of fps) is easily attainable.